# Which cryptographic attacks can AES 128-bit withstand?

Tags: aes, attack

Most of the articles and forums are stating that the Brute Force attack can test the strength of an encryption algorithm. However, I am looking for those attacks that AES can withstand for the testing simulation purpose.

Comment: Hybrid Chaos? What does it mean? Do the answers of this question satisfy you [Has AES-128 been fully broken?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/76738/18298)

Comment: @kelalaka nope.... I am new to cryptography and I would like to perform any attacks to an AES encryption and to prove that AES is strong enough. But I could not find any attacks that can be performed .....

Comment: Other than the side-channel attacks, AES withstand attacks in 20 years. AES has shown itself quite resilient to attacks.

Comment: Is there any attacks that is easy to perform to the AES for testing simulation purpose?

Comment: Cache attacks, you can find codes around. But remember these are not a direct mathematical attack on the AES. You cannot bruteforce a 128-bit key size.

Comment: Got ya, thanks a lot mate .... your answer is very helpful !

Comment: @zebiskin "_I would like to perform any attacks to an AES encryption and to prove that AES is strong enough_" - attacks can only prove the weakness of an algorithm, not its strength