# Is multiple encryption with CTR mode vulnerable to meet-in-the-middle attacks?

Tags: ctr, multiple-encryption, meet-in-the-middle-attack

Let's suppose I want to encrypt my disk partition with AES-256 in CTR mode 2 times using two different keys and IVs.

Will I get 512 bits of encryption strength?

Comment: You are correct, the [1D-meet-in-the-middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meet-in-the-middle_attack#MITM_algorithm) attack applies. If you have four or more matched plain and cipher blocks, you have a good chance of uniquely identifying the key without additional testing. Thus the overall complexity will be a little over 256-bits. Note that the memory requirements are *much* bigger than for exhaustive attacks.

Comment: Why do you need 512-bit encryption?

Comment: @kelalaka -- I'm too paranoid and I want to keep my encryption safe against quantum computers.

Comment: Use 256-bit key size then you are safe : [Has AES-128 been fully broken?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/76738/18298)

Comment: @DanielS CTR doesn't have decryption process, I still believe that multiple encryption with CTR mode is immune to MITM attacks.