Are hash functions with a security of 128 bits quantum-safe?
I read in the Q/A on this site: " https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/76738/has-aes-128-been-fully-broken"
that AES-128 is resistant to PQC. This is true even when Grover's algorithm was used because the operations on QC are much slower and the algorithm isn't parallelizable.
What about modern hash function families like SHA-2 or SHA-3? Will SHAKE128 be vulnerable?

Please have a look at my changes they will help when asking additional questions. Using a spell check and / or re-reading your post is mandatory on this Q/A site. Note that SHAKE128 is not a 128 bit hash function. 128 bit hash functions have an output size of 128 bits. SHAKE is a XOF with a security of 128 bits.

What do you mean by security of 128 bits? pre-image security or collision security? Hash functions with 128-bit output have no collision security for classical birthday attacks. There is Brassard et al.'s attack over Grover for hash functions, however, most of the time the space cost is not considered. Also, the number of calls of the Grover machine is a huge problem due to the successive evaluations and the setup time. Note that Grover machine can be parallelized and we gain $\sqrt{k}$ speed up for $k$ parallel machines.

@kelalaka how can Grovers algorithm be parallelized? I read that it can be executed only serial

Yes, here from more experts, Can we speed up the Grover's Algorithm by running parallel processes?
